# C - Threads using execl suicides itself

Tags: c, pthreads, scandir

here's my problem: my code should execute all the executable files (i.e. all the binaries and all the scripts) in the current directory, concurrently.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <dirent.h>   

/* struct created for passing arguments at every thread */
struct thread_data {

  long  thread_id;
  char *nome_file;
};

/* task of every thread */
void *work(void *thread_args) {

  long tid;
  char *name;
  struct thread_data *my_data;

  my_data = (struct thread_data *)thread_args;
  tid = my_data -> thread_id;
  name = my_data -> nome_file;
  printf("thread number %ld get file %s\n", tid, name); 
  execl(name, name, (char *)0);
  printf("execl failed\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int filter(const struct dirent *entry) {

  /* Filter for scandir(): I consider only the regular files */
  if(entry -> d_type == DT_REG)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main() {

  int n, rc;
  long t;  
  struct dirent **namelist;
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  void *status;
  /* Number of regular files in the current directory */
  n = scandir(".", &namelist, filter, alphasort);
  if(n < 0) {
    perror("scandir()");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  /* How many threads? */
  pthread_t thread[n];
  /* Every thread will receive one instance of the struct thread_data */
  struct thread_data thread_data_array[n];

  /* With this, I'm sure my threads will be joinable */
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  for(t=0; t<n; t++) {
    printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    /* Filling the arguments in the struct */
    thread_data_array[t].thread_id = t;
    thread_data_array[t].nome_file = namelist[t] -> d_name;
    rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], &attr, work, (void *)&thread_data_array[t]);
    if(rc) {
       printf("ERROR: pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  for(t=0; t<n; t++) {
    rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
    if(rc) {
      printf("ERROR: pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Main: join succeeded on thread %ld\n", t);
  }

  printf("Main: program finished. Quitting...\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

My program successfully reads the regular files in the current dir, and every thread get one file per time, but when the first binary or script is executed, the program quits!
Here's an example of its execution...

```
Main: creating thread 0
Main: creating thread 1
Main: creating thread 2
Main: creating thread 3
Main: creating thread 4
Main: creating thread 5
Main: creating thread 6
thread number 0 get file slide.pdf
execl failed
thread number 1 get file hello.sh
Congrats, you executed this script, I'm hello.sh!
```

And then, he won't continue the execution with other files. Perhaps the error is in the execl return value in case of success...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the `exec`-family functions **replace** the current **process** (not thread) by the named executable when they succeed; the only way they return is on failure. You should be using either `fork` followed by `execl`, or preferably, `posix_spawn`.

Comment: I don't understand where should I put the posix_spawn :(

Comment: The way you're trying to use `execl` now is the way you'd use `posix_spawn`.